# How to allow users who have cancelled their accounts to re-activate / re-enable them?

Tags: users

If a user cancels their account on a Drupal 7 site, is there a way to allow them to re-activate their account without requiring administrator intervention?

If a user has second thoughts and wants to rejoin the site using the same e-mail address, I would like to make it easy for them.  I have set the **Account cancellation method** to *Disable the account but keep the content*.

Comment: If a user tries to register an account using the email used from a blocked account, the user will get an error about using an email already in use, and get a link to reset the password, but resetting the password doesn't work for blocked accounts. I didn't find a module that re-enables an account when a user tries to register using the email address already used from a blocked account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this using the Rules and Flag modules.  I created a per-user flag, "Cancel my account," and the made some rules that would automatically unpublish all content posted by a user if and only if that user flagged himself/herself.  I then created another set of rules to re-publish everything if the user then unflagged the "Cancel my account" flag on himself/herself.

Answer (score 1):

There are two URL which can help you in achieving this. First you will have to use [Advance User](http://drupal.org/project/advuser) module & then you can extends some hooks of it according to your need for account re-activation.
There is a blog written on similar issue which may help you - [Enable/Disable User](http://www.fagioli.biz/drupal-enable-disable-users-advanced-users-module).

I hope you find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use hook_user_cancel_methods_alter for this.
Later on I think when user wants to reactivate his/her account. It will active.

Comment: Could you explain more?  It's not clear to me how using that hook would allow users to reactivate their accounts.